# if x in list. if statement being ignored?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, if-statement

I'm using python 3.8, and I don't understand why my first if statement is being ignored. City is a class which has an attribute name. I first tried to just use an if statement with the city object itself, and then tried using the names and comparing that instead. When I run this every iteration leads to the first if statement being passed (even when it shouldn't), and the else never being executed.

```
    for city in self.cities:
        citylist.append(city.name)
    for road in sortedroadlist:
        city1 = road[0].name
        city2 = road[1].name
        if city1 or city2 in citylist:
            finallist.append(road)
            if city1 in citylist:
                citylist.remove(city1)
            if city2 in citylist:
                citylist.remove(city2)
        else:
            sortedroadlist.remove(road)
```

Comment: `if city1 or` will most likely always be true (unless `city1` itself evaluates to a falsy value)

Comment: `if city1 or city2 in citylist:` is **not** the same as `if (city1 in citylist) or (city2 in citylist):`.